# Show that the inclusion $V \to U$ is nullhomotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Show that if a space $X$ is deformation retract to a point $x \in X$, then for each neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ $\exists$ a neighbourhood $V \subset U$ of $x$ s.t the inclusion $V \to U$ is nullhomotopic.

Now considering the deformation retract $f: X \times I \to X$ if we just restrict $X$ to $U$ then we are done I think (check!!). Here is basically my question that is it enough to take $V=U$ or I have to modify it?

Comment: You have to modify.

Comment: Then what will be the modification?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify it. Think about taking $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $U$ to be a neighborhood that is an annulus. Then $U$ is clearly not homotopic to a point, so the identity map on itself cannot be nullhomotopic.

Comment: Then what will be the modification?